# How long should I keep financial records for closed brokerage accounts?

Tags: united-states, record-keeping

For example, if I close a brokerage account and move the monies to an account with a separate company, is there a reason to keep records beyond the tax year, or [beyond the time to retain tax documents](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75228/how-long-should-i-keep-my-tax-documents-and-why)?

Answer (score 1):

I recently closed a brokerage account and the brokerage company charged me a fee for closing the account because they have to keep records for 7 years. [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidmarotta/2014/01/26/how-long-should-i-keep-financial-and-tax-records/#3401fe884da5) states to

> keep brokerage statements indefinitely for taxable accounts. You are
>   responsible for reporting the cost basis of any security you sell to
>   calculate the capital gains tax.

So in today's world with being able to have electronic copies of everything, it shouldn't be hard to keep a copy somewhere.